# Push to Heroku being rejected, breaking in package.json

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm

When trying to push to Heroku I keep getting this error:

```
remote: !       Push rejected to infinite-cove-33100.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/infinite-cove-33100.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

It always breaks at:

```
remote:        > mern_ecommerce@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_43ebd568
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend     
remote:
remote:        up to date in 0.284s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! syscall open
remote: npm ERR! path /tmp/build_43ebd568/frontend/package.json
remote: npm ERR! errno -2
remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_43ebd568/frontend/package.json'       
remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

All versions in the package.json are accurate, everything that's needed in .gitignore is there including node_modules, heroku has the right buildpack and everything has been added and committed with git.

I've been through: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
and no solution yet.

This is the package.json where it keeps breaking:

```
{
  "name": "mern_ecommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {"node": "14.15.1"},
  "description": "MERN shopping cart app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seeder",
    "data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"
  },
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "e
    xpress": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",

    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "node": "^14.15.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the original problem was but I was able to deploy by using the deploy tab on the Heroku site via linking github... not how I wanted to do it but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having trouble with their Heroku builds, it might be worthwhile to install npx by running `npm install -g npx` and let it inspect the contents of your package.json file by running `npx @heroku/update-node-build-script`.

Also see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@heroku/update-node-build-script

For manual inspection check: https://help.heroku.com/P5IMU3MP/heroku-node-js-build-script-change-faq

Answer (score 0):

try running `npm install` sometimes it's happening because you manually updated your package.json, which will not affect the package-lock.json hence it's different from the remote one hence can not get deployed